# Android JSON Translate HTML Entities

Tags: android, html-entities

I'm trying to pull a JSON output and populate a ListView with it. Everything is working, except the resulting text has html entities in it instead of the symbols, for example £ is `&pound;` and - is `&ndash;`

I've looked at the JSON feed output manually, via the url, and it's not showing the entities but is showing £ and - and such.

The code the populate the ListView is,

```
                 ListAdapter adapter;
                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                       MainActivity.this, productsList,
                       R.layout.list_row, new String[] { TAG_BODY, TAG_TITLE},
                       new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.headline });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I've found a few answers around but they all consist of either fixing on server, (which is outputting fine in this case), or using WebView which I'd rather not do.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by checking "manually" ? Open the url in a browser ? poster ? the browser will interpret the html entities ...

Comment: mind to show us your code to get your JSON to productList. On a side note, this looks like a server issue, under no circumstances i could think of android/java would encode your Strings to html entities without you explicitly changing default settings.

Comment: Turns out the problem is with a select number of entries in the database so the problem lies with the PHP handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too late but here is how you do it

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
        {
           textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)));
           textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)));

        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
        }
```

[Here](http://devnextdoor.com/2016/11/26/decoding-html-entities-in-android/) is an article about handling HTML in JSON output

Comment: I don't even remember what project this was for now. I do remember though that the problem turned out to be a server-side one and once patched wasn't an issue. Regardless this looks like a solution so I've marked it correct, but I can't test it so if anyone finds this and uses it, please add a comment to confirm whether it works as intended or not.

Comment: Thanks for accepting @JamesKrawczyk. I can confirm this works as I use it very often.